# Is the series convergent? unclear formulation?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n!}{3*5*7*9*....*(2n+1)}$$

I am not quite sure what this means. Say n=1, does the denominator stay at $3$? But then why not just use $(2n+1)$? But if the denominator goes on and stops at $(2(1)+1)=3$, what does this mean? Where does it end?

Comment: The denominator is $(2n+1)! /(2^{n}n!)$. Use Stirling's formula.

Comment: It may help to write out some more terms. The series looks like: $$\frac{1!}3 + \frac{2!}{3\times 5} + \frac{3!}{3\times 5 \times 7} + \frac{4!}{3\times 5\times 7 \times 9} + \cdots$$ Does that make more sense to you now? I suppose that the $8$ in the original formula was a typo - should be $9$.

Comment: How does this series compare to $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2} + \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^3 + \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^4 + \cdots$ ? It is easy to show that if the original series is denoted $a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + \cdots $ that $\displaystyle \frac{a_{(n+1)}}{a_n} = \frac{n+1}{2n+3} < \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy i dont think we are supposed to....

Comment: @WhatsUp Thank you!!!!!!!!!